# Starscream's socket.isConnected is always returning false

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

I'm developing an iOS application using Swift that connects to an Android device via sockets. I've implemented Starscream and was able to connect to the other device. My issue is that when I print something on the websocketDidConnect delegate method, it does not print. Also when I print socket.isConnected, it prints false. Kindly help me. Thanks. Other alternatives to Starscream are also welcome, thanks!

Here is my code:

```
    import Starscream
    class SettingsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, WebSocketDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        let socket = WebSocket(url: NSURL(string: "ws://\(ipAddressTextField.text!):4000/")!)
        socket.connect()

        print("socket.isConnected \(socket.isConnected)") //this one is false

        socket.onConnect = {
            print("Connected...") // does not print
        }

        socket.onDisconnect = { (error: NSError?) in
            print("websocket is disconnected: \(error?.localizedDescription)") // this one prints when I turn the wifi off
        }

        socket.onData = { (data: NSData) in
            print("got some data: \(data.length)")

        }

    }

func websocketDidConnect(ws: WebSocket) {
    print("websocket is connected")
}

func websocketDidDisconnect(ws: WebSocket, error: NSError?) {
    if let e = error {
        print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("websocket disconnected")
    }
}

func websocketDidReceiveMessage(ws: WebSocket, text: String) {
    print("Received text: \(text)")
}

func websocketDidReceiveData(ws: WebSocket, data: NSData) {
    print("Received data: \(data.length)")
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it as a class property otherwise it will be released as it gets out of viewDidLoad method.